# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar 2 columna en una sola?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo un campo de fechas en postgrest y quiero que mediante un query, puede obtener la fecha más antigua y la más reciente

```
2023-02-16
2023-02-08
2023-03-13
2023-03-02
2023-03-16


SELECT DISTINCT  MIN(p.fecha), MAX(p.fecha)  FROM public.events p
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no lo necesito en 2 columnas diferente, si no que se muestren estás 2 fechas en una sola columna.

Comment: usa max y min... y listo!! sin where, sin join, sin nada...

Comment: Me parece que la respuesta de Japv resuelve lo que describes en los detalles, pero que tu pregunta en realidad no es cómo obtener el registro más antiguo y el más reciente, sino cómo mostrar esos datos en una misma columna. Quizá podrías modificar el título para que se refleje eso y sea de utilidad para otros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una variante puede ser la siguiente:

```
select T.fecha
from
(
 select min(p.fecha) as fecha  
 from public.events p
 union
 select max(p.fecha) as fecha  
 from public.events p
) T
order by T.fecha
```

Usas el **operador de conjuntos union** el cual sirve para unir los resultados de varias consultas y devolver un único conjunto de datos.

**Actualización**:

Sobre la consulta más interna, aplicamos una consulta más general, la cual se va a encargar de ordenar los resultados obtenidos de manera ascendente aplicando la **claúsula order by** por el **campo fecha**.

Comment: Gracias a amigo por compartir tus conocimientos con la comunidad. Dios te bendiga